# Twitter Cards for Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request

It would be cool to have some added metadata so that questions linked on Twitter look nice, via:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards

I considered writing something in front of Stack Overflow for the particular questions I'm tweeting about, but it probably makes sense to have this be a function of Stack Exchange in general.

Opinions?

Comment: This is now implemented--the cards look great.